# Explain python unstack() simply

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I am trying to annotate my python code before I rewrite it to avoid unstack() because of [an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49482356/assertionerror-gaps-in-blk-ref-locs-when-unstack-dataframe). Im stumped when it comes to explaining unstack to myself, even after reading the docs and seeing the output. Can someone explain what it does without using phrases like "pivot a level"?

[Definition](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) from docs:

> Pivot a level of the (necessarily hierarchical) index labels, returning a DataFrame having a new level of column labels whose inner-most level consists of the pivoted index labels. If the index is not a MultiIndex, the output will be a Series (the analogue of stack when the columns are not a MultiIndex). The level involved will automatically get sorted.

Here is the code Im attempting to annotate:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from numpy.core.defchararray import add

d = {'vote': [100, 50,1,23,55,67,89,44], 
     'vote2': [10, 2,18,26,77,99,9,40], 
     'ballot1': ['a','b','a','a','b','a','c','c'],
     'voteId':[1,2,3,4,5,'aaa',7,'NaN']}
df1=pd.DataFrame(d)
#######################################################################
print(df1)
#Set the DataFrame index (row labels) using columns voteId and ballot1
s=df1[:10].set_index(['voteId','ballot1'],verify_integrity=True)
print(s)
#unstack (default -1). ?????
# s=s.unstack()
# s.columns=s.columns.map('(ballot1={0[1]}){0[0]}'.format) 
# dflw=pd.DataFrame(s)
# print(df1)
# print(dflw)
```

Comment: printing the dataframe before and after using `unstack()` should illustrate quite clearly what `unstack` does with your dataframe. Especially if all the possible dataframes you might wanna feed to unstack look similar.

Comment: @Joooeey I understand what it does, im just struggling to explain it in simple words because quite a few operations happen at once

Answer (score 1):

`DataFrame.unstack()` simply moves ("pivots") some of the levels of a MultiIndex (hierarchically indexed) DataFrame to become column labels instead of row labels. There are clear examples in the documentation.

Comment: so what your saying is that unstack sets the second column provided to it as column labels? And that "pivot" is the same as "make this column the column labels"?

Comment: @Rilcon42: I think you've got it right.  Try some examples and check it.